# IE11 Input type Text content goes to new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I am using simple text input (type=text) along with the angularJS in my project.

HTML Markup

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="startDate"
       ng-class="{'fieldBorder' : dateRangeSelIndex == 0}"
       ng-focus="setBorderOnFocuse($event,0)" />
```

I am using following JavaScript code to set the border of input when it get focus.

```
$scope.setBorderOnFocuse = function ($event, selIndex) {
                                $scope.dateRangeSelIndex = 0;
                            }
```

The behaviour works fine in Firefox and Chrome Browser but when I test it in IE11, The content of the input box goes to second line after the click-course position.

Check following screenshot of behaviour. 
[image]

I already checked the CSS applied to it and the input box has enough length to handle the content in one line.

Thanks in Advance!

**Edit**
CSS Applied to the input

```
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 27px;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: normal;
```

JS Fiddler for same http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/21997/

I cannot reproduce the same behaviour in jsfiddler but I found one interesting thing that this might be due to the cross added by IE11 in input text on focus.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that reproduces this on IE11?

Comment: Hi Adam, http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/21997/ is fiddler for same. But I cannot reproduce the same into fiddler.

Comment: I would suggest completely blocking out IE and forcing users to use firefox or chrome lol but that is impossible. However, read the following which is why you see that behavior https://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/542711-borders-inside-out Basically stupid IE makes the border inside of the input if I am correct which causes the said issue. I think you just got to set the correct mode for IE i.e quirk mode, etc

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the same, but was unable to do. I see that the `css` is having width of `200px` but from the screenshot, it is looking somewhat smaller. Can you make sure that the intended `css` with the same width is getting applied.

Comment: Thanks Shashank, Actually I applied lesser width in jsfiddler to reproduce the same.

Comment: When you are working with inputs and border styles you don´t want your text to "jump around" when you focus the input field. I would recommend to always set a border, not only on hover or focus. Maybe you want to get rid of the outline in chrome too? `input { border:1px solid #ccc; outline:0; }`

Comment: Thanks Roland Krinne, I tried your suggestion by applying border in normal state with different colour but no luck.